# Regex To Exclude Characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to prevent a field from having a double underscore or spaces. I want the error to happen when there is not a match on the field, instead of trying to match to check for the error. I almost have the pattern, but I still cannot seem to prevent a match when the string starts with double underscores. Here is what I have:

(^(?:^\s)(?:.(?!(?:__|\s)))*$)

Comment: @Jan Underscores are allowed, only double-underscores are invalid.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: Right you are, misread that.

Comment: Try [`String pattern = "^(?:(?!(?:__|\\s)).)*$"`](https://regex101.com/r/cV3cD1/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^([^_\s]|(_(?!_)))*$
```

This should match any string which is made up of characters which are not `_` or whitespace, and any characters which are a `_` but not followed by a `_`.

Answer (score 0):

What about "(\\s\\s|__)" looking only for double spaces or double underscore :

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("(\\s\\s|__)");

//If the pattern is not found the String is valid
System.out.println( ! reg.matcher(" v a l i d e").find());
System.out.println( ! reg.matcher("__invalide").find());
System.out.println( ! reg.matcher("_valide_").find());
System.out.println( ! reg.matcher("InVALIDE  ").find());
System.out.println( ! reg.matcher("in__va  lid").find());
```

Comment: I only need to know if there are two spaces, no need to match more it won't be efficient is this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with sth. like:

```
^(?:(?!__|\s{2,}).)+$
```

This will prevent two underscores or two spaces directly following. See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hX8oK6/4).